# Android, can I put AsyncTask in a separate class and have a callback?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm just learning about AsyncTask and want to use it as a separate class, rather then a subclass.

For example,

```
class inetloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String response = "";

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e("xx",result);
        // how do I pass this result back to the thread, that created me?
    }


}
```

and the main(ui) thread:

```
inetloader il = new inetloader();
il.execute("http://www.google.com");
//il.onResult()
//{
    ///do something...
//}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can put it in a separate class, but most people don't because its purpose is usually a lot more clear if it's an inner class. If you're going to reuse it in lots of activities, go ahead.

Comment: I plan using it for different purposes, like if I call it from here, on result it should do that and that, if I call it from there, on result it should do something else... therefor if I'll keep it in the same class and have it call a function from that class on result, i'll have to make a new AsyncTask for every kind of action that it has to do onresult...

Comment: use interface, just implement your activity by a interface and in onPostExcute() of Asyn class call mContext.implementedMethod().

Comment: Having it in a separate class also helps with version control & change management.

Comment: BTW pls start your class names with a capital letter e.g. "InetLoader" - just basic Java convention.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use a interface. Something like:

```
interface CallBackListener{
  public void callback();
}
```

Then do this in your UI thread:

```
inetloader il = new inetloader();
li.setListener(this);
il.execute("http://www.google.com");
```

In inetloader, add:

```
   CallBackListener mListener;

   public void setListener(CallBackListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
   }
```

then In postExecute(), do:

```
   mListener.callback();
```

Comment: Thanks, sound like it's the right direction to go. Especially if I could create a CallBackListener with the inetloader il = new inetloader(); and pass it into the il object.

Comment: Hmm... strange, I don't have a "CallBackListener" in android v3, maybe it goes by some other name?

Comment: @RogerTravis Yeah you have to create a CallBackListener interface yourself. And don't forget to add "implements CallBackLisnter" for your main UI class.

Comment: ouch, it seems to give just one @Override public void callback() { for the UI thread. Is there a way for me to make multiple callbacks(){} on for each inetloader object I make?

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the activity instance to constructor and call activity function from there...
Like use interface :

```
public interface ResultUpdatable {

   public void setResult(Object obj);
   }
```

Implement this in the Activity and pass in the constructor of Async task and update the result from `onPostExecute` using `setResult` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
inetloader il = new inetloader();
il.execute("http://www.google.com");

String result = il.get();//put it in try-catch
                ^^^^^^^^
```

`here you get result which is in onPostExecute(String result)`

Comment: Not really :( I need some sort of an onResult listener, that will trigger once the AsyncTask finished, because querying some servers might take a while. On the other hand, putting the il.get() into a while(true) loop might sound too primitive, won't it? :) are there any better options?

Comment: @Samir : This is a really bad idea. Whilst it does allow retrieving a result from the `AsyncTask`, using the `get()` method will block the UI thread and effectively turns what should be an asynchronous procedure into a synchronous one. The only valid use for the `get()` method I have ever come up with would be for 'chaining' two `AsyncTasks`.