# Calling method of activitiy from a non-activity class in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm implementing a class which `extends AsyncTask` and I perform an http request within this class. The class is not an `Activity` and is located in a seperate java file because I want to use this class several times.

I instantiate an object of this class in my `Activity`, to execute the http request in a separate thread. When the thread executes, I want to call a method of my `Activity`.

How do I implement this? I need the result of the http request in my `Activity` but I can't handle this so far.

This is the code for the thread task...

```
public class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public String result = "";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://bla/index.php?" + urls[0]);
        // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        // convert response to string
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

}
}
```

And this is part of my `Activity` code that creates the thread class...

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);


    PostRequest task = new PostRequest();
    task.execute(new String[] { "action=getUsers" });
    task.onPostExecute(task.result) {

    }
}

public void Display(String result) {
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String value = json_data.getString("name");
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
        text.setText(value);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the activity reference in constructor......

as

```
public class PostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public String result = "";
private Activity mActivity;

 public PostRequest(Activity activity){
          super();
         mActivity = activity;
}

......
```

Comment: But how do i now access the method of this activity? I've tried to do this like mActivity.Display(); but this doesn't work... Thanks so far!

Comment: either use you activty name in place of the Activity in PostRequest function of just type cast activity to your activity....

Comment: @DheereshSingh, thanks, I thought that typecasting to Activity should be enough but you're right, it should be typecasted to real activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do a `onPostExecute()` as this is called after the process `doInBackground` has completed and then you can use the reference of the activity passed into the constructor of the AsyncTask to run any time of method on your UI.

Just remember that `onPostExecute()` method runs on a UI thread so here from this method you can try to modify your view if needed.

Answer (score 0):

See this question...[can-i-put-asynctask-in-a-separate-class-and-have-a-callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768449/android-can-i-put-asynctask-in-a-separate-class-and-have-a-callback) and the accepted answer. If you want a re-usable `AysncTask` as a stand-alone class then using a listener as a callback for all of your activities is the best way to do it.