# Why do the samples don´t appear in my androidplot graph?

Tags: android, plot, android-asynctask, androidplot

I´m modifying some data into an asynctask. I´m using androdidplot since I want to see the points I generate into the code but I´m struggling since I can´t see them.

I checked the question in this link:  [Access UI elements from Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100236/access-ui-elements-from-asynctask)
and it points out to declare **XYPlot** and **LineAndPointFormatter** as members of the class and initialize them into onCreate. After that I´m just plotting from onPostExecute. I checked through a LOG if the data is being generated and there´s no problem. Could someone  help me or give me a clue please ?

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button startStopButton;
    boolean started = false;
    TextView tv1; //not ussed so far

    GenerateSamples samplesTask;

    XYPlot plot;
    ArrayList<Integer> Vector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int DataY;

    XYSeries series ;
    LineAndPointFormatter seriesFormat ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startStopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartStopButton);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); //Not used so far

        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.Grafica);

        plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL,20); //x
        plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 5000);   //y

        plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0) );
        plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        plot.setRangeBoundaries(-20000, 20000, BoundaryMode.FIXED); //y
        plot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 100, BoundaryMode.FIXED); //x

           series    = new SimpleXYSeries(  Vector, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "signal") ;
        seriesFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb (127, 255, 0 ), 0x000000, 0x000000,null ) ;


        /** Listener when the button is clicked. */
        startStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (started) {
                    started = false;
                    startStopButton.setText("Start");
                    samplesTask.cancel(true);
                } else {
                    started = true;
                    startStopButton.setText("Stop");
                    samplesTask = new GenerateSamples();
                    samplesTask.execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called when the button is pressed
     */
    public class GenerateSamples extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void > {

        public int[] generateRandom() {

            int[]random = new int [20] ;
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i <= random.length-1; i++)
               //random[i]= rand.nextInt(32761);
                random[i] = rand.nextInt(32761 + 1 + 32762) - 32761 ;
                //random[i] = rand.nextInt(30 + 1 +30) - 30 ;

            return random;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //It returns a boolean. It needs a void = nothing to do with the task.
            //It can get data from a method into the class without the need of getting it from the argument
            //of the asynctask class.

            int[] point ;
            point = generateRandom();

            for (int i = 0; i <= point.length-1; i++) {
                point[i] = point[i]+5;
                longTask();

                publishProgress(point[i]);


                if( isCancelled() )
                   break;
            }
           return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //It returns a void = it returns nothing. It needs an integer to do the task ;
           DataY=  values[0];
            Vector.add(DataY);
            Log.d("Samples log", "samples: " + DataY );

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            plot.addSeries(series,seriesFormat) ;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished Task!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancelled Task!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void longTask() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100); //100 milliseconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"

    >


    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/Grafica"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"

        androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="20dp"


        ap:rangeTickLabelTextSize="11sp"
        ap:domainTickLabelTextSize="11sp"

        ap:rangeOriginTickLabelTextSize="11sp"

        ap:domainOriginTickLabelTextSize="11sp"

        />
    <Button android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/StartStopButton"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    </Button>


    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv1" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside OnPostExecute, try this:

```
plot.addSeries(series,seriesFormat) 
plot.redraw()
```

Comment: Your answer do the trick, however I had to add : ` series    = new SimpleXYSeries(  Vector, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "signal") ;`

Comment: you are welcome, we had the same problem at nearly the same time!