# How can I pass an async task from one activity to another?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on an android app and I have an async task in one activity and I want to use that async task into another activity. Can I do so?

Comment: You can move async task to new class and listen to it using [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), so you can use in all the classes.

Answer (score 2):

I think AsyncTask do use for in his class.Beacause This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at least one method (doInBackground(Params...)), and most often will override a second one (onPostExecute(Result).)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible at all. The one idea that came to my mind is to use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and do an `AsyncTask` in it. The service has to be bound.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can .create a new asynctask class with your common operation. And you can create callback interface and your activity must implement interface to get appropriate callback of asynctask.

[Android, can I put AsyncTask in a separate class and have a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768449/android-can-i-put-asynctask-in-a-separate-class-and-have-a-callback)

Comment: Interesting answer. May test this when I get a chance and if it works I think it's the solution.